# When can addition be split in double sigma notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, real-numbers

> Question -  $\displaystyle \sum _{i=0}^n\displaystyle
> \sum_{j=0}^n(i+j)\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=?$

The steps written in the book are -
$\displaystyle \sum _{i=0}^n\displaystyle
\sum_{j=0}^n(i+j)\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=\displaystyle \sum _{i=0}^n\displaystyle
\sum_{j=0}^niC_iC_j+jC_iC_j$

Now they have split it as
$\displaystyle \sum _{i=0}^n\displaystyle
\sum_{j=0}^niC_iC_j+jC_iC_j=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n iC_i\sum_{j=0}^nC_j+\sum_{i=0}^nCi\sum_{j=0}^njC_j$

And then they have solved the problem further.

My question is what are the condition when splitting of addition terms into two sigmas as we did in the last step is allowed? Note that we can manually verify that the step is true but are there any specific conditions where we can split addition?

Note : $C_i= \binom{n}{i}$ and similarly for $j$.

Comment: $\sum_{i,j}a_ib_j=\sum_ia_i\sum_jb_j$ is the identity used here.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Please read my question carefully. I have asked about addition not multiplication.

Comment: Addition is commutative and associative so it always splits any way you like. $\sum_{k}(a_k+b_k)=\sum_k a_k+\sum_k b_k$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek My question is about double summation . Note that $\sum_i^n \sum_j^n (i+j)$ cannot be split like that!

Comment: $\sum_i\sum_j(i+j) = \sum_i\sum_j i + \sum_i\sum_j j$. Let me stop here. I clearly don't know what you mean by "splitting of addition terms into two sigmas ". The whole transformation which happens in that line is the combination of the two identities I wrote in my two comments, first the sum and then the product in each of the two sums..

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek  if we split $\sum_i^n \sum_j^n (i+j) $ as $\sum_i^n \sum_j^n i +  \sum_i^n \sum_j^n j $then answer comes as $(n)(n+1)$. In reality answer is $n(n+1)^2$. Why does it fail here?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Ma_j = N\cdot \sum_{j=1}^M a_j$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whenever the limits of summation are not dependent on each other, and the summand is separable into a product of independent factors, the double sum can be rewritten as the product of single sums.  In your case, all these criteria apply.

If $f(i,j) = g(i)h(j)$, then

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n f(i,j) = \sum_{i=0}^n g(i) \sum_{j=0}^n h(j).$$

You might be thinking $$f(i,j) = (i+j)\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}$$
admits no such factorization.  And you are correct!  But if you distribute the binomial coefficients over the sum $i+j$, then $$f(i,j) = i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{j} + j \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} = f_1(i,j) + f_2(i,j),$$
where we choose functions
$$f_1(i,j) = i\binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{j} = g_1(i) g_1(j), \quad g_1(i) = i \binom{n}{i}, \quad g_2(j) = \binom{n}{j},$$
and similarly
$$f_2(i,j) = j \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{j} = g_2(i) g_2(j), \quad g_1(i) = \binom{n}{i}, \quad g_2(j) = j \binom{n}{j},$$

and now each of the terms $f_1$ and $f_2$ do admit such a factorization.  And because sums distribute over sums, that is to say

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n f(i,j) = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n f_1(i,j) + \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n f_2(i,j),$$

now each of these two double sums is separable according to the first equation above, which is precisely what is stated in your question.

Comment: Great Explanation. But if we split $\sum_i^n \sum_j^n (i+j) $ as $\sum_i^n \sum_j^n i +  \sum_i^n \sum_j^n j $then answer comes as $(n)(n+1)$. In reality answer is $n(n+1)^2$. Why does it fail here?

Comment: @Aleph $$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n i = \left(\sum_{i=0}^n i\right) \color{red}{\left(\sum_{j=0}^n 1\right)}.$$  Then $$\sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$ and $$\sum_{j=0}^n 1 = n+1.$$  There is no contradiction.